# Detect when the MPMoviePlayerController is paused or stopped

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

There are two symptoms I am experiencing:

1) when I call `[ourMovie release]` in my `movieFinished:` method **below**, I am told I am releasing something already released .. isn’t the `[sentNotification object]` passed to –`movieFinished:` a copy and therefore something I have to release ??

2) totally unrelated to (1) is that when add a NSNotification observer for `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification`, the movie does not show up.  No detectable error, just a no-show ??  My goal here is to detect when the user pauses or stops the playback and then pushes the Home button to send my app to the background.  When the app returns to the foreground, I want to continue the movie where the user left it when he pushed the pause or stop button .. not start from scratch as my app does now.

Before I proceed, I do have the following in my **AppDelegate**:

```
[notificationCenter addObserver:self
                       selector:@selector(pauseApp)
                           name:@"UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification"
                         object:ourApp];
```

FYI: my –pauseApp eventually calls `[ourMovie pause]`

In my –playVideo: method I have

```
[notificationCenter addObserver:self
                       selector:@selector(movieFinished:)
                           name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                         object:ourMovie];

[notificationCenter addObserver:self
                       selector:@selector(pauseDownload)
                           name:@"MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification"
                         object:ourMovie];
```

and for my –movieFinished method I have

```
- (void )movieFinished:(NSNotification *)sentNotification
{
    NSObject *theNotifyObject = [sentNotification object];

    NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

    if ( [theNotifyObject isKindOfClass:[MPMoviePlayerController class]] )
    {
        MPMoviePlayerController *ourMovie = (MPMoviePlayerController *)theNotifyObject;

        [notificationCenter removeObserver:self
                                      name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                    object:ourMovie];

        [notificationCenter removeObserver:self
                                      name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                    object:ourMovie];

        [ourMovie pause];
        [ourMovie stop];
        [ourMovie release];   // release what we don't own   ???
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) No, you don't have to release `ourMovie`. You are not copying anything, you are just passing an object as an argument to a method, hence referencing the same place in memory. So if your previous memory management was correct when creating the object, you don't have to do anything at this point.

2) If you want the video to play from the same place in time, then why are you calling `stop` after you call `pause` on `ourMovie`?

This a citation from Apple documentation on [MPMediaPlayBack](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaPlayback_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/MPMediaPlayback)'s `stop` method: **"This method stops playback of the current item and resets the playhead to the start of the item."**